# Why aren't my tomatillos fruiting?

Tags: tomatillos

We have two tomatillo plants that have been growing very well and have a ton of flowers. However, so far we have only had one single fruit! We had three plants last year that did very well with lots of fruit, so we're very confused why this year's are doing so poorly. We're located in DC and getting temps in the 80s this time of year. What could cause them to flower but not fruit?

Comment: Lack of pollinators, for one. How many are you seeing on the flowers? Have you tried resorting to a paintbrush?

Comment: Aside from overall pollinator stress, pesticide-happy neighbors can greatly impact your local pollinator supply.

Comment: @Ecnerwal We definitely have no shortage of pollinators. We have wildflowers nearby and the bees and flies are everywhere. We also have peppers that are doing fine.

Comment: @Ecnerwal We've tried the paintbrush method. It almost seems like there's no pollen in the flowers that are there.

Comment: What variety of tomatillo are you growing? Have you grown this variety before?

Comment: @Jurp Honestly not sure. Last year's came from a small nursery and this year's came from a big home improvement store.

Comment: Well now that I've posted this, we've had a half-dozen others start to fruit. Maybe it was just too early in the season for this variety.